# How to implement cookies consent to be aligned with the EU GDRP regulations?

Tags: cookies, sap-commerce-cloud, cookieconsent

To be aligned with the EU **GDRP regulations**, i want to implement the cookie consent in a webshop (with cookies categorization).

We have multiple cookies category : **Strictly Necessary
(Required), Analytics , Social Media and Advertising**.

Of course, no problem with the Strictly Necessary cookies, but for the other cookies category, a prior user consent is needed to use set those cookies.

Here is some useful information:

- My webshop is  based on SAP Commerce Hybris (based on JEE, JSP spring
  MVC).
- We are using Google tag manager in our webshop to manage tags
  and also manage some third-party scripts.

My question is :

**What is the best solution to implemnt cookies consent?**

**Remark** : From my first investigation, i found that GTM is a possible option, is it indeed a good option?

Regards,

Comment: What did you do? I have the same question.